# How to git rebase, preserving merges and moving all branches?

Tags: git, git-rebase

We develop in multiple teams using git for version control.  Each team delivers features into a team branch (merging) like this:

```
*    [integration_team1]  Merge team1_featureB into integration_team1
|\
| *  [team1_featureB]     Comment about feature B code
|/
*                         Merge team1_featureA into integration_team1
|\
| *  [team1_featureA]     Comment about feature A code
|/
*    [release]

(Names in square brackets are branch names.)
```

Periodically, we deliver the integration branch into [release], preserving history. With one team this is easy: merge [integration_team1] into [release], fast-forwarding.  However, when there are two or more teams involved, then the graph may look like this:

```
*        [integration_team1][release] Merge team1_featureB into integration_team1
|\
| *      [team1_featureB]     Comment about feature B code
|/
*                             Merge team1_featureA into integration_team1
|\
| *      [team1_featureA]     Comment about feature A code
| |
| | *    [integration_team2]  Merge team2_featureD into integration_team2
| | |\
| | | *  [team2_featureD]     Comment about feature D code
| | |/
\ | *                         Merge team2_featureC into integration_team2
 \| |\
  \ | *  [team2_featureC]     Comment about feature C code
   \|/
    *
```

I want to rebase [integration_team2] onto [release], preserving the merges AND moving all branches. If I do:

```
git checkout integration_team2
git rebase --rebase-merges release
```

Then I get this graph:

```
*    [integration_team2]  Merge team2_featureD into integration_team2
|\
| *                       Comment about feature D code
|/
*                         Merge team2_featureC into integration_team2
|\
| *                       Comment about feature C code
|/
*    [integration_team1][release] Merge team1_featureB into integration_team1
|\
| *  [team1_featureB]     Comment about feature B code
|/
*                         Merge team1_featureA into integration_team1
|\
| *  [team1_featureA]     Comment about feature A code
| |
| | *    [team2_featureD] Comment about feature D code
| | |
\ | *                     Merge team2_featureC into integration_team2
 \| |\
  \ | *  [team2_featureC] Comment about feature C code
   \|/
    *
```

The structure of the rebase is right, but the associated branches do not get moved.   Is there a way to move those? Specifically, the basic technical requirement: When each commit is processed for the rebase, any branch on that commit which exists on the remote should be moved to the newly rebased (cherry-picked) commit.  If that is done, the result would be:

```
*    [integration_team2]  Merge team2_featureD into integration_team2
|\
| *  [team2_featureD]     Comment about feature D code
|/
*                         Merge team2_featureC into integration_team2
|\
| *  [team2_featureC]     Comment about feature C code
|/
*    [integration_team1][release] Merge team1_featureB into integration_team1
|\
| *  [team1_featureB]     Comment about feature B code
|/
*                         Merge team1_featureA into integration_team1
|\
| *  [team1_featureA]     Comment about feature A code
|/
*
```

From this point, the [release] branch can simply be fast-forwarded and we have a clean history.
Is there any way to accomplish this, perhaps using plumbing commands?

Comment: Now that we have `--rebase-merges` (which can reconstruct merges "correctly", for some suitable definition of "correct") it's even more important for Git to support this out of the box. Git *doesn't* support this, though, and making it work "correctly"—for some suitable definition of "correct", again—is *very hard*. You'll need to manually force all the other branch names into the rebased commit graph.

Comment: Yes. I do "git checkout branch" and "git rebase <commithash>" for each branch.  It is a pain -- especially when working across 45 repositories for 12 teams.  In reality, we typically just use merges and live with a horribly tangled history.

Comment: I think the "right" way to do this (again, the whole notion of "correct" is suspect here as there are multiple right answers) is that `git rebase --rebase-merges` should leave a record of (old-commit-id = new-commit-id) mappings in a log somewhere, and if you and Git are satisfied that the rebase is now correctly concluded, some subset (possibly all) of the branches whose hash IDs name commits in the "old" table should be moved, as if by `git branch -f`, to the corresponding "new". This is how `git filter-branch` handles the name updates upon finishing the filter-copy pass.

Comment: @torek: Do you know anything about the git "plumbing" commands? I'm wondering if there is enough stuff exposed that I could implement this in a script by using the same capabilities as filter-branch.

Comment: The plumbing commands are those intended for use in scripting: for instance, `git rev-parse` and `git rev-list` are basic workhorse commands with which you can write scripts. In this case, that doesn't help that much: the root of the problem is that Git is missing anything approaching Mercurial's "evolve" extension (and the fact that evolve is an *extension* means that Mercurial is missing it too, in a way). The map file I suggested here is kind of a poor-man's substitute for proper linkage between original (obsoleted) and new replacement commits.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase` only operates on the current branch. The only solution I can think of here is resetting each branch individually:

```
git checkout <branch>
git reset --hard <hash>
```

You can get the hash from `git log` and look for the rebased commit with the same message as the original commit.

Comment: Yes, I do something like that.  I actually use rebase and the new commit number for each branch as that is a bit safer.  But, that's a ton of work for large numbers of branches.

Comment: I'd just use `git branch -f` while still on the rebased branch - that's fewer commands, and relatively easily scripted as well (use `git log` to find the new hash IDs, use that to build the script of `git branch -f`s).

Answer (score -1):

> I want to rebase [integration_team2] onto [release], preserving the merges AND moving all branches.

The rebase you want to do will rewrite all the [integration_team2] commits, merging all the changes currently in [release] into *each* of them, as if team 2 had initially based its work off the current [release] rather than the original one.

This will invalidate all testing on each of the rebased commits.  If you want a universal rule for Git histories, "published commits must not break the build" would have to top the list.  You'd have to go back and retest every single one of them after the rebase.

If you're merging two independently-developed-and-tested published branches, *merge them*.  That's what's really happening here, you're merging the branches.  If your history is lies, this helps nobody.  the ..._team2 branch was not developed based on ..._team1's work, not tested based on it, you're merging the completed feature sets, say so.